# Java: Difference with dis.read() and dis.readUTF() in DataInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, datainputstream

Simple Question.

What is Difference with `dis.read()` and `dis.readUTF()`?

For example, `dis.read()` only read to byte array, and `dis.readUTF()` access `String` type.

Is it correct?

If Server has implements `dis.readUTF()`, it can not read byte stream?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(mEnabled)
    {
        if (!mFileReceive) {
            try {
                // read
                String tmpStr = dis.readUTF();
                // here come `dis.readUTF()` <- it is can not read byte array?

                mStringBuffer += tmpStr;

                if (tmpStr.length() >= 4096)
                    continue;
                System.out.println("Print : " + mStringBuffer);

                parse = new ParseJSON(null, mStringBuffer.toString());
                // Ack Message
                if (mAckEnabled) {
                    mFileName = "{opcode:0x06,ACK:C" + parse.getParsedData().get("ACK").substring(1) + "}";
                    dos.writeUTF(mFileName);
                    dos.flush();
                    System.out.println("Ack Message Send : " + mFileName);
                    mFileName = null;
                }
                if (parse.getParsedData().get("opcode").equals("155")) {
                    mFileReceive = true;
                }
                parse.clear();
                parse = null;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("ServerThread disconnect");
                break;
            }
```

Comment: (1) What part of the Javadoc didn't you understand? (2) "If Server has implements dis.readUTF(), it can not read byte stream?" is meaningless. `DataInputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` implement both methods.

Comment: @EJP My Question is 'dis.readUTF' can read byte stream. JAVADOC says **Bytes for this operation are read from the contained input stream.** Client send to Server Byte array. But Server didn't catch it.

Comment: *All* those APIs read from the byte stream. However `readUTF()` reads the format that `writeUTF() writes. If you're not calling `writeUTF()` I don't understand why you would want to call `readUTF()`.

Comment: @EJP Thank you so much, `readUTF()`, `writeUTF()` look like partner.

Comment: @EJP My Ubuntu uses Locale KO_KR.utf8. So, I intent to Use 'readUTF()'. Thank you So Much. Your Advice is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readUTF() reads from the stream in a representation of a Unicode character string encoded in modified UTF-8 format; this string of characters is then returned as a String.

You should use read method which takes bytes array as an argument. Here is its explanation:

**public final int read(byte[] b) throws IOException**

Reads some number of bytes from the contained input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.

Comment: @11684 Exactly, That's my curios.

Comment: @EJP Client send to Server byte array Data.

Comment: @reinhard.lee In which case you should have mentioned that in your question. You said nothing about what the client was writing.

Comment: @EJP I'm sorry. I didn't know that.